# Custom row order by mirrored column values

Tags: r, sorting, row

I have a dataset like this:

```
Tab1 <- read.table(text = "
   nodepair ES1 ++ -- +- -+ 0+ +0 0- -0 00 ES2
1     A1_A1   3  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   4
2     A1_A1   3  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   5
3     A1_A1   4  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   3
4     A1_A1   4  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   5
5     A1_A1   5  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 15   3
6     A1_A1   5  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 15   4
7     A2_A1   3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   4
8     A2_A1   3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   5
9     A2_A1   4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 21   5
10    A2_A1   4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 21   3
11    A2_A1   5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   4
12    A2_A1   5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   3   
", header = TRUE)
```

I need to order this first by nodepair, but then by both ES1 and ES2 such that the mirror combination of each ES1 and ES2 are sorted like this:

```
Tab2 <- read.table(text = "
   nodepair ES1 ++ -- +- -+ 0+ +0 0- -0 00 ES2
1     A1_A1   3  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   4
3     A1_A1   4  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   3
2     A1_A1   3  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   5
5     A1_A1   5  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 15   3
4     A1_A1   4  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 16   5
6     A1_A1   5  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 15   4
7     A2_A1   3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   4
10    A2_A1   4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 21   3
8     A2_A1   3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   5
12    A2_A1   5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   3
9     A2_A1   4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 21   5
11    A2_A1   5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20   4    
", header = TRUE)
```

I've tried various versions of arrange and group by but can't seem to crack it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dplyr**

This is another solution using dplyr and ifelse

```
library(dplyr)
Tab1 %>%
  mutate(ES3=ifelse(ES1<ES2,paste(ES1,ES2,sep=','),paste(ES2,ES1,sep=','))) %>% 
  arrange(nodepair,ES3)
```

Answer (score 2):

We need an additional sorting id:

```
Tab1$sortid <- apply(Tab1[c('ES1','ES2')],1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="_"))
Tab1[order(Tab1$nodepair,Tab1$sortid),]

   nodepair ES1 X.. X...1 X...2 X...3 X0. X.0 X0..1 X.0.1 X00
1     A1_A1   3   0     4     0     0   0   0     0     0  16
3     A1_A1   4   0     5     0     0   0   0     0     0  16
2     A1_A1   3   0     4     0     0   0   0     0     0  16
5     A1_A1   5   0     5     0     0   0   0     0     0  15
4     A1_A1   4   0     5     0     0   0   0     0     0  16
6     A1_A1   5   0     5     0     0   0   0     0     0  15
7     A2_A1   3   0     0     0     0   0   0     0     0  20
10    A2_A1   4   0     0     0     0   0   0     0     0  21
8     A2_A1   3   0     0     0     0   0   0     0     0  20
12    A2_A1   5   0     0     0     0   0   0     0     0  20
9     A2_A1   4   0     0     0     0   0   0     0     0  21
11    A2_A1   5   0     0     0     0   0   0     0     0  20
   ES2 sortid
1    4    3_4
3    3    3_4
2    5    3_5
5    3    3_5
4    5    4_5
6    4    4_5
7    4    3_4
10   3    3_4
8    5    3_5
12   3    3_5
9    5    4_5
11   4    4_5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

#### Helper function

```
f <- \(e) bind_rows(combn(unique(e),2,\(v) tibble(ES1=v, ES2=rev(v)), F))
```

#### Apply function by nodepair, and join

```
inner_join(reframe(Tab1,f(ES1), .by=nodepair), Tab1)
```

Output:

```
   nodepair ES1 ES2 ++ -- +- -+ 0+ +0 0- -0 00
1     A1_A1   3   4  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16
2     A1_A1   4   3  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 16
3     A1_A1   3   5  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16
4     A1_A1   5   3  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 15
5     A1_A1   4   5  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 16
6     A1_A1   5   4  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 15
7     A2_A1   3   4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20
8     A2_A1   4   3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 21
9     A2_A1   3   5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20
10    A2_A1   5   3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20
11    A2_A1   4   5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 21
12    A2_A1   5   4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20
```